# Is there a way to save multiple power-point presentations with different names using a for-loop through python-pptx?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

```
from pptx import Presentation  
prs = Presentation()  
prs.save('test2.pptx')
```

So I am using the above code to save a blank ppt in some location. Now if I want to save multiple ppts with names `test1.ppt`, `test2.ppt`, `test3.ppt` and so on, is there a way to loop it using a for-loop. Note that I am trying create multiple power-point presentations and not multiple slides in a single presentation. Really wish, the owner of pptx (@Scanny) can look into this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty straightforward:

```
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation()
for i in Range(1, 4):
    prs.save('test{}.pptx'.format(i))
```

Comment: Just to elaborate on this @MHarshit, the `Presentation.save()` method writes to the file named in its single argument each time it is called. So you can easily save as many copies of a given presentation as you like by simply providing distinct file paths/names to successive `.save()` calls.